# Yammer as a support forum

Tags: yammer

we are in desperate need for a support forum within a large cooperation. It would make life much easier if an existing tool with a lot of users would be used.
The thoughts goes to yammer.

But what are the posibilities with yammer api to get statistics about e.g. reply time.
Are there ways of tagging specific topics as "support" and "resolved"?
And assign it to a group of ppl or specific person? (if it's AD groups then it's fine, or groups defined in Yammer or outlook mailgroup)

Any help would be good to get this forward!

Comment: I appreciate your question, but since it's not asking a specific programming question the StackOverflow community are likely to downvote/close it. A better place to ask for this advice would be over on the Yammer Tech Community site (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Yammer/ct-p/Yammer) which is more flexible about questions like yours. The product can be used very effectively as a support forum within an organisation, but that is just one of the things you can use it for. The Tech Community users can describe their experiences for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!